# php oop how connect two class (extended from one parent)

Tags: php, oop

is possible to connect two class like this ?
we want first login with admin class then use $user without passing variables

```
class app {

 $user;

}


class admin extends app {

 function login() {
   $this->user = "lamar";
 }

}



class song extends app {

  function add() {
   // add somthing with $this->user
  }

}

$admin = new admin();
$admin->login();
```

now how to use class song to add song with user "lamar" ?

Comment: use dependency injection in song class

Comment: *Is* `admin` *an* `app`? *Is* `song` *an* `app`? Could you substitute a `song` anywhere you'd need an `app`? I don't think so. Logically this inheritance structure makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Connecting classes and use their values without passing variables is not possible. Have a look at dependency injection to get access to a class within another.

Regarding to your example it could look like this:

```
class User {
 private $username;

 function getUsername() {
   return $this->username;
 }
}

class Song {
  private $user;

  function __construct(User $user) {
     $this->user = $user;
  }

  function getUser() {
    return $user;
  }
}
```

It might be a good idea to optimize your approach for app, admin and song otherwise your architecture could become quite complicated.